# показать и скрыть div по клику на button

Tags: html

Есть код 
HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHideContent").click(function () {
        if ($("#content").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#content").show("slow");
        } else {
            $("#content").hide("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showHideContent">Показать/Скрыть</button>

<div id="content" style="display:none;">Содержание, которое скрыто по-умолчанию. Покажется/скроется при клике на одну и ту же ссылку.</div>
```

скрывает и показывает content , а нужно два button:
Код:

```
<button id="showContent">Показать</button>
<button id="HideContent">Скрыть</button>
```

Один показывает , другой скрывает, какой код должен быть?

Comment: собссн, на один (showHideContent) повесить клик с `show` на другой (HideContent) клик с `hide`

Comment: Понятно что так, но в js не понимаю , потому и написал сюда для помощи написания кода

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот что мне нужно было, может кому то надо:

```js
let content = document.getElementById("content")
let show = document.getElementById("showContent")
let hide = document.getElementById("hideContent")

show.addEventListener("click", () => {
    content.style.display = "block"
})

hide.addEventListener("click", () => {
    content.style.display = "none"
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>No Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="showContent">Показать</button>
        <button id="hideContent">Скрыть</button>

        <div id="content" style="display:none;">Содержание, которое скрыто по-умолчанию. Покажется/скроется при клике на соответствующие кнопки.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```